# Angular2 - *ngIf : How to show a specific element?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am willing to show only a specific element using **ngIf**; however, for some reason, it does not work.

**The issue:** When I click to show only a specific element, all the other elements shows up!

**The code:**

HTML (elements is taken from an async request)

```
<ion-col *ngFor="#finalFormat of elements">
<div *ngIf="currentElement">
<div>Show this element</div>
</div>
<div (click)="showThis(finalFormat.elementName)" *ngIf="!currentElement">CLICK TO SHOW</div></ion-col>
```

JS:

```
    showThis(element){
    if(this.currentElement === element){
      return;
    }
    this.currentElement = element;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would update the test like this:

```
<div *ngIf="currentElement === finalFormat.elementName">
  (...)
</div>
```

Same for the "CLICK TO SHOW" block:

```
<div (click)="showThis(finalFormat.elementName)" 
     *ngIf="!currentElement !== finalFormat.elementName">
  CLICK TO SHOW
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be simpler:

```
<ion-col *ngFor="#finalFormat of elements">
  <div *ngIf="finalFormat.currentElement">
    <div>Show this element</div>
  </div>
  <div (click)="showThis(finalFormat)" *ngIf="!finalElement.currentElement">CLICK TO SHOW</div>
</ion-col>
```

and in controller:

```
showThis(element) {
  element.currentElement = !element.currentElement;
}
```

So you basically just modify `currentElement` property of individual `finalFormat` objects.